# What is the fastest way to iterate over multibyte string in PHP?

Tags: php, multibyte

Question is as simple as that:

> What is **the fastest way** to iterate over multibyte string in PHP?

I suggest the following one:

```
<?php

$s = "bong-zhoor";

for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($s, 'UTF-8'); $i++) {
    $ch = mb_substr($s, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');

    echo $ch . ' ';
}
```

Looking for improvements, if any.

Comment: Calculate the length of the string just once.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666306/how-to-iterate-utf-8-string-in-php - lots of methods covered in this question already..

Comment: Do `for($i=0, $c=mb_strlen($s, 'UTF-8'); $i < $c; $i++){}`. Recently made an answer for that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42515276/4982088)

Comment: @Ankh `preg_split()` is hardly efficient..

Comment: @Ankh Definetelly a duplicate, but still wanna keep my question because it has more *findable* title when googling.